# VSCode -- Preview (i.e. head) a CSV file as the default open option?

Tags: csv, visual-studio-code, large-files

I was working with a large CSV file (> 1 GB), I wanted to preview what the columns were and what the data looked like by exploring the top ~100-1000 rows of the data alongside the headers.

When I open the file, my computer hangs for quite awhile due to the size of the file. However, I noticed there is a preview large file: head (I believe through the RainbowCSV extension?)  in the context menu that loads much faster and provides the functionality I would want in the strong majority of cases (previewing large files for structure rather than opening them entirely).

Is there anyway to set this context menu option for previewing a large file as the default behavior when clicking on a .csv file in the File Explorer? I would prefer this so I do not accidentally make my computer hang when clicking on a file.

Bonus points if anyone can point me to an extension that let's you paginate CSV files by default.

Comment: This should definitely be an option. What the hell VS Code?

Answer (score 1):

Shamelessly stealing this from [a blog post](https://alexjamesbrown.medium.com/opening-first-few-lines-of-a-huge-file-with-vs-code-alex-brown-738d86663a6): if you have `head` installed and VS Code's directory is in your `PATH` environment variable, this command will pipe the first 100 lines of `filename.csv` into Code:

`head -n100 filename.csv | code -`